# implementing translation in ionic 3 folder structure

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, internationalization, ionic3

I am trying to convert my ionic 1 app to ionic 3. Previously, i have implemented the translated json file per module in ionic 1 using angular translate directive.

However, it seems that most example for ionic 3 that i see online put the language json file unders assets in such ways

```
assets
  i18n
  - en-US.json
  - en-GB.json
```

To me, there is many flaw and **disadvantages** on this, which includes 
  - Our company do set up a lock in the file to the first person who modified, which means that when one person is modifying a file, other cannot modified the same file in the server unless the person release it. Imagine that there will be a lot of people is competing for the file. 
  - It might be very slow if the translation file is large. 
  - Hard to maintain when it grows larger.

So, is there any specific reason above format is use? And what are the structure of translation you all is using?

My proposal of improvement of the folder structure is as follow. Hope to get input from stackoverflow community.

```
pages
    page1
    - page1.html
    - page1.scss
    - i18n (folder)
      - en-US.json
      - en-GB.json

    page2
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

That is the recommended approach by the Ionic team if you'll use the [**ngx-translate/core**](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core) library. Because it works using `HttpClientModule` and `HttpClient`. So you have to put your translation files inside the `assets` folder.

**Note:** You can modify these files locally when you develop the app. After that, you can commit those changes into `git` or whatever the version control you're using.